# Can I attach a Camera to a Sphere which was created with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, camera, geometry

So basically I have an object with a Geometry Nodes Modifier. Within the Geometry Nodes I add a couple of UV Spheres and move them using the transform node. What I am trying to achieve is attaching a camera to one of those UV Spheres. Question is, is it even feasible and if yes, how do I achieve that?

Comment: What does "attaching a camera" mean? If you mean just following/copying its position, you can use the answers in this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/281656/71578 (just change the constraint to "Copy Location" or other relevant ones as you wish)

Comment: Hi, MartenZander .. this does look as if this question is, functionally, a duplicate of Kuboå s suggested link. (At the moment, this looks like a feasible, but  tricky thing to do.)  If it isn't the same, and you can edit to clarify the distinction, we can re-open your post.